# Entity Framework entity state management Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have used EF (now with 6.1.1) for a relevant time. But every time I need to work with more than one entity inside a controller (using MVC) I lose myself.

The state management of entities causes me great confusion and when I think I understand the operation then comes another surprise.

For example (my current confusion):

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public C c { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public C c { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string anotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CopyEntityAction(A a){
    var b = new B() {
        c = a.c // <== here is the problem
    };
    db.Bs.Add(b);
}
```

What I want to do is copy (create another entity) C from A to B, and not link to the same C.Id

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your time

* I think somethings EF could take care automatically

**Edit 1**

I tried this too:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CopyEntityAction(A a){
    var b = new B();

    var c2 = a.c;
    db.Entry(c2).State = EntityState.Added;
    b.c = c2;

    db.Bs.Add(b);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this. Otherwise you are dealing with the same exact C object, not creating a new one.

```
var b = new B() {
        c = new C { Id = a.c.Id, anotherProperty = a.c.Anotherproperty } // <== here is the problem
    };
```

You may also need to explicitly need to add the new C to the context's C collection.

Comment: Hey SethMW, thanks for your suggestion, but I think when you mark an entity with a "EntityState.Added" it ignores the Id and creates a new one... no?

Comment: Wow, where is the guy with 3rd answer that mencioned Automapper? I liked his sugestion too. He removed the answer :(

Comment: AutoMapper would help if you had a lot of extra properties to map over when copying entities, or mapping them to ViewModels, etc. If you really do only have a couple, it may not be worth the overhead.

Comment: I found this: "var clonedBlog = context.Entry(blog).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's really not all that confusing. It boils down to where that data comes from. When you retrieve an object from Entity Framework it is "attached" to your context. However, when you *post* data to an action and have the modelbinder new up an instance of your entity with that data (via including it as a parameter), it is *not* attached. That means Entity Framework knows nothing about this object. It doesn't know where it came from, whether it's ever been saved before or not (is this going to be an update or an insert?), etc. So, it's on you to tell it what to do at that point. That is what the `EntityState` enum is for.

Comment: Hey Chris, my question is more about copy an entity with a new Id and not about detached objects coming from Action parameter. So, object A is irrelevant to me, I need to understand how to create B with C from another object (A in this example). Thanks